# MinGW make: copy: command not found

Tags: makefile, mingw

I'm trying to compile hp2xx on Windows 10 using MinGW. My makefile is a straight copy of the dosdjgpp.mak file from the makes directory. I have c:\MinGW\bin and C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin in the path.

The make operation fails at the first copy. The makefile line it is failing on is

```
pbuf.o: picbuf.o
    copy picbuf.o pbuf.o
```

and the error is

```
copy picbuf.o pbuf.o
make: copy: Command not found
make: *** [pbuf.o] Error 127
```

From the same command prompt I can use copy OK, so why can't make find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `mingw/bin` contains the linux style copy command `cp` so try

```
pbuf.o: picbuf.o
    cp picbuf.o pbuf.o
```

You may want to add the windows copy path if not already included

Comment: Thanks, that's done it - I replaced "copy" with "cp" in the makefile and that error has gone.  Now I have new errors to investigate :)

Comment: if its another windows/linux command you may want to learn the linux variant s.. or and the windows bin path : o